# To get rid of Safari "top hits"

Tags: macos, mac, safari

Is it possible to prevent Safari on Mac from showing me top hits?

[image]

I was told that I need to clear the history and bookmarks for this first, and yes, if you delete history and bookmarks, you won't see top hits. But as long as you will add bookmarks again, top hits are shown again. And I suspect they will return even if you won't add bookmarks, that is, when your history will grow to some number of entries.

Maybe I'm wrong in some point? Maybe there is a really good way to get rid of them?

Comment: Try Safari / Preferences / Search / Smart Search Field

Comment: I've already tried this. Maybe I've missed something there, though...